# Trying to find the approximate solution of this non-linear system

Tags: calculus, numerical-methods

So, I'm trying to find an approximate solution for the non-linear system $$n·8.0000003=p-\sin(q),$$$$n·7.9999996=q-\sin(q),$$$$ n·16.0000003=p+q-\sin(p+q),$$ where $n,p,q>0$. Ive tried Newton Raphson etc but everything leads me to the trivial solution. Thanks.

Comment: Because this system is from an astrodynamic problem, and therefore this should have a positive solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's sketch the implicit plots of the following three equations:
\begin{align}
1: \ \ \frac{p-\sin (q)}{8.0000003}&=\frac{q-\sin (q)}{7.9999996} \\
2: \ \ \frac{p-\sin (q)}{8.0000003}&=\frac{-\sin (p+q)+p+q}{16.0000003} \\ 
3: \ \ \frac{q-\sin (q)}{7.9999996}&=\frac{-\sin (p+q)+p+q}{16.0000003} \\
\end{align}

[image]

This gives us some clue for reasonable choices of $p$, $q$, and (from the original equations) $n$. In fact, looking back at those original equations, it seems likely that there are solutions *close* to $p=q=k\pi$, $n=k\pi/8$. I actually had to perturb those a touch to get the following solutions out of Mathematica's `FindRoot` command:

$$
\begin{array}{l}
 \{p\to 3.14159,q\to 3.14159,n\to 0.392699\} \\
 \{p\to 6.29271,q\to 6.29271,n\to 0.785398\} \\
 \{p\to 9.42478,q\to 9.42478,n\to 1.1781\} \\
\end{array}
$$